# Force no empty cell depending on another cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible in Excel to force a no empty cell depending on another cell?
I mean if you type in e.g. a casenumber in A1, then you have to type in something in B1 and C1 also.
And it should be dynamic, so it should Work on all the cells in column B and C, but it should only look at the cell in the same row in column A.

Just some more details....

Because the original sheets isn't designed to be exported, I need to copy the appropiate data to another sheet before exporting.

So I have a ungly sheets which filled out cell I copy to a nicer layout on another sheet, which in turn I export to csv.

I use this code to copy the data:

Private Sub CopyAllNonBlanksInRange()
    With Sheets("Flexhal Tilbudsregistrering")
    .Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Ark1").Range("A1")
    .Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Ark1").Range("B1")
    .Columns("G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Ark1").Range("C1")
    End With
end sub

So the problem is in the copy process, as it as it should only copies the cells which contains data.

At this point I can only see that I have to run through all row to check if they are filled out and do the copy based on that. That seems like a mess, and I'm not even sure of how to do that.

Comment: You'd want to enforce something that depends on user action and will happen *in the future*? I'm not sure you can do that in programming. Maybe in politics. :-)

Comment: lol classy comment... ;-)

Comment: I was going to say to try data validation but I don't think that will work after all. Because you can simply ignore the cell.

Comment: You'll probably need to use a UserForm.

Comment: My problem is as following.

It is a order document, in which some users type in an order number, a project name and a costumer name. 

I'm exporting this to a csv file, for some other system which needs the data.

I when discovered that they hasn't typed in the project name and costumer name, and that causes the export to be faulty as the data dn't match up, because I use SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) to copy the data, and that removes the empty rows, causing af mismatch between project number and project name.

I was shoping I somewho could get a mesaagebox to appear.

Comment: @Mystique I'd take the advice of D_Bester and create a User Form to input data, while the sheet itself would be protected from direct editing. Like this you'd know that if something is inputted, you may refuse storing the data into the sheet unless is complete.

Comment: Alternatively, modify your export routine to validate the data before creating the csv file.

Comment: I'd say keep the loop like check if the cell is empty. if it is throw the input box until user enters a value or use conditional formatting and mark the row in bright color to let know user that he/she has to fill it any way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with an **Event macro**  The macro would enforce this scenario:

1. start with **all** cells protected except **A1**
2. once the user has filled **A1,** both **B1** and **C1** become un-protected
3. once the user has filled *both* **B1** and **C1, A2** become un-protected

etc.

**EDIT#1**

First enter and run this macro to setup the sheet:

```
Sub SETUPP()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells.Clear
    Cells.Locked = False
        With Range("A1")
            .Select
            Cells.Locked = True
            .Locked = False
        End With
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then enter this **Event** macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range, N As Long
Set A = Range("A:A")
N = Target.Row
If Not Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Cells.Locked = True
        Range("B" & N & ":C" & N).Locked = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect
Else
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B" & N & ":C" & N)) = 2 Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
            Range("A" & N + 1).Select
            Cells.Locked = True
            Range("A" & N + 1).Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do this in vba

Answer (score 0):

@gary's I'm sure your answear is valid, but since last I managed to solved it myself through this code:

```
Dim celleværdi As String
Dim i As Long
Dim række As Long
Dim startcelle As String
række = 1
nederstecelle = "E65000"

Range(nederstecelle).End(xlUp).Select 'ud fra variblen celle finder vi den sidste celle med værdi i
sidstecelle = ActiveCell.Row
'MsgBox sidstecelle

For i = 1 To sidstecelle 'looper kun igennem rækkerne indtil sidste udfyldte celle
    If Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then 'er celleværsien forskellig fra tom, så kopiere den over i Ark2
         Cells(i, 5).Select
         Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Ark1").Cells(række, 1)
         række = række + 1
     End If
Next i
```

And you code seems a little to much overkill for the task. 
I still get the empty cells, but now the get copied as they should, then maybe I'll do some checking and paste in my own text if a cell is empty.

But thank for the help, if I haven't solved it my selv, I'm sure it would have helped me.